# How to get inner content of data in dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

i'm new with python and can't get the inner content of the the dictionary.
i have a "detail" as a dictionary and i would like to pull data from "properties" so i will have "time" and "distinct_id" as keys

Right now the keys in the dictionary are "event" and "properties" and  would like to go deeper in the dictionary

example of dictionary "details":

```
{"event":"User Profile - Page View","properties":{"time":1428969601,"distinct_id":"14cb3d99b195-0feaf7b1c-5c267370-c0000-14cb3d99b1a220"}}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `d["properties"]["time"]`, what do you not understand about that?

Answer (score 1):

Each dictionary (instance of dict) comes with a method `__getitem__(self, index)`, for which [] is a syntactic suggar. In order to access an unnested dictionary, you would normally use details['event'].

Since nested dictionary is just another dictionary, the same applies further: `details['properties']['time']` will return the 'time' of nested dictionary.

If you want the code to be a bit nicer, you can assign the first dictionary to a variable

```
properties = details['properties']
```

and access the attributes as you would in normal (not nested) dictionary

```
print properties['time']
print properties['distinct_id']
```

Answer (score -2):

dict = {"event":"User Profile - Page View","properties":{"time":1428969601,"distinct_id":"14cb3d99b195-0feaf7b1c-5c267370-c0000-14cb3d99b1a220"}}

dict['properties']['time']